# default ubuntustudio 15.04 install crypto passphrase works fine except for swap

Tags: server, encryption, swap, 15.04, ubuntu-studio

I did a fresh install of ubuntustudio 15.04 (64b), with activated encryption.
I sometime get a request to provide a passphrase for ubuntu--studio--vg-swap_1, for example if I execute `sudo service isc-dhcp-server restart` in which case I get the request for the swap crypto passphrase.
Every passphrase I enter, including the one that works for the system is wrong.
I get no message and the command does not seem to have executed (e.g. isc-dhcp-server does not seem to have restarted).
I need this dhcp server, as well as postfix and everything I need to start with the service command.
Why does there seem to be a different passphrase for swap?